# Blazor WebAssembly always find resources over https .Net5

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor-webassembly

I'm having some throubles when deploy my Webassembly App into my IIS server.
By client's requirements the application needs to be accesed over http, when the application is requested the index.html is displayed, however, all the application resources are requested over https and this is cause an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu8F4.png)
Is any way to make it works?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check if any URL rewrite rule(s) that enforce HTTPS are applied on your site. And if possible, please create a new site to host your app and check if it can work well.